# Unable to delete a ufw rule that has a space in it

Tags: bash, ssh, ufw

After installing `ufw` on several servers, I see the following rules:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
224.0.0.251 mDNS           ALLOW       Anywhere
SSH (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
ff02::fb mDNS              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

I want to delete the `SSH (v6)` rule from all my servers, so I tried this:

```
ufw delete allow SSH (v6)
```

But that gave me the error

```
Could not delete non-existent rule
Could not delete non-existent rule (v6)
```

I tried

```
ufw delete allow SSH\ \(v6\)
```

But that gave me the error

```
ERROR: Bad port
```

What is the correct syntax to put into my bash script so that I can delete ufw rules that have a space in it?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the rule by its number:

```
sudo ufw status numbered
```

And then:

```
sudo ufw delete <number of the desired rule>
```

Comment: The number changes depending on which server you're on.  Is there a way to do this without knowing the line number so that I can automate this from a bash script?